# Javascript functions

Tags: javascript

```
function validate()
{
   alert('Welcome to my Web Site!');
   document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HImagePath_Image1').ImageUrl="";
   alert('GOOD BYE!');
}
alert('Welcome to my Web Site!');
```

This executes, but next line doesn't show any action. What is the issue with that? Can anyone tell me is id of my image control and ImageUrl is property of my image control.

Comment: You are not giving anything in the URL, so how it will retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You cant access the serverside property ImageUrl in javascript. because javascript runs on the client this property is now the src attribute on the image tag.

Comment: @Dean North u mean this???
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HImagePath_Image1').src="";

Comment: try alerting 

document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HImagePath_Image1')

to see if you have actually got the element first.

Comment: Ok, this means that the id may be incorrect. Can you view the source of the html page in your web browser and post some of the html that includes the image tag.

Comment: @Dean North <td rowspan="4" style="padding-left: 67px">
                                                                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="74px" Height="84px" /></td>
                                                                    <td rowspan="3">

Comment: This is the server side source code. Can you run the site in internet explorer, then right click and view source then post that too. This way we can see what the actual html is that the javascript is executing against.

Comment: @Dean North<td rowspan="4" style="padding-left: 67px">
                                                                        <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcEmployee_tpPersonal_Image1" src="" style="height:84px;width:74px;border-width:0px;" /></td>
                                                                    <td rowspan="3">                                                                             
                                                                    </td>

Comment: Are you trying to hide the image or replace it with a new one? If you are trying to hide it then you can hide it by adding a display:none style to it instead of trying to set the src to ""

Comment: i m replacing it with old image

Comment: So are you trying document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tcEmployee_tpPersonal_Image1').src = "mynewimage.png"

Comment: in my cs file this is code to show image(c#.net code) string file_ext = Path.GetFileName(Image1.ImageUrl);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/EmpImages/" + file_ext;

Comment: This is your server side code again. I thought you wanted to change the image in javascript when you run the validate function?

Comment: no i tried in javascript to asign it null so that may i got new image in same browser but it did not worked

Comment: oooooooo nooo i m trying this for 5 days but did not find any solution :-(